# Would this be on topic here?

Tags: support, on-topic-definition, asking-questions

I would like to ask:

Are the Stack Exchange Community Managers exempt from overtime?

I am guessing that no one who is not a CM would know the answer for certain.  But I am hoping that experts in the workplace might be able to make an educated guess.  That is why I thought of asking this question here.

If it needs a little tweaking to be on topic here, constructive suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 6):

As you are asking something that is **company-specific (specific to SE)** then that would be **off-topic.**

One of the possible ways for a post to be off-topic is precisely by being company-specific.

To make it on-topic you should try to address this issue.

---

*Note:* It could be worth seeing if this question could be on-topic on Meta SE.

If I had to guess this is about SE itself (its staff) so it could be on-topic over there. However be sure to verify. Anyways, who better than SE staff to ask this question specific to their company.

(again, check if it's on-topic there in case it were not)

Comment: I'm just concerned that the question might not be asked there.  Or that it might be considered impertinent.  That happened to me this weekend with another question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339847/has-average-response-time-changed-since-the-firing-and-if-so-by-how-much.  I wonder if there's a way to somehow generalize and give a description of the type of company and function.  Maybe there's a general pattern.

Comment: @aparente001 Even if there is a pattern, that still doesn't tell you anything about how this specific company you're looking at handles it. That's really why the company-specific close reason exists. Something you potentially could ask here is in the vein of "*How do I determine what a company's overtime culture is?*"

Comment: @Lilienthal - Thank you.  Do you think it would be more productive to include the name of the company I'm interested in, or would it be better to omit that?

Comment: @aparente001 including the name would make it company-specific, as mentioned in the answer. Lilienthal's suggestion is something that you could ask and be on-topic :)